# Multilevel menu on mobile with touchstart on the icon within the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

There is multilevel menu where each `<li>` contains `<a>`. On desktop the submenu is opened with `:hover` and all is good.
On mobile I want to replace `:hover` with click on the font awesome caret-down icon click to open the submenu. However in below html the `<a>`
 captures the touchstart.

How to capture click on icon that is inside the link and have rest of the link still clickable?

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.hover').bind('touchstart', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('hover_effect');
            });
        });
```

This is the menu structure:

```
<li class="hover"><a href="/link1">WordPress Development<i class="fa fa-caret-down hover" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/link2">Themes</a></li>
        <li><a href="/link3">Plugins</a></li>
        <li class="hover"><a href="/link4">Custom Post Types<i class="fa fa-caret-down hover" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <ul>
                <li class="hover"><a href="/link5">Portfolios</a></li>
                <li class="hover"><a href="/link6">Testimonials</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/link7">Options</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is event or function which will work not on link clicked but on your fontawesome icon. And because in yur navigation you have only one  tag, you don't need to provide it id or class, just replace ".hover" to ".hover i":

`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.hover i').bind('touchstart', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).parent().toggleClass('hover_effect');
  });
});
```

`

Comment: If clicking on the icon on mobile, then still the `<a>` captures the touchstart, not `<i>`